# Python script OSError when called from Java runtime

Tags: java, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a python script (call it `python_prog.py`) that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tempfile
import subprocess

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as file:
    # populate file with data
    # then call another program, passing file.name as an arg:
    return subprocess.check_output([command_line_program, file.name, option1, option2])
```

I can call `python_prog.py` by name from the command line:

```
$>  python_prog.py  option1 option2
```

This runs just fine.  The trouble comes from trying to call `python_prog.py` from a java program.  I am using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` in the java code:

```
        String[] command = new String[] {
                "python_prog.py",
                "option1",
                "option2"
        };

        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder errorBuilder  = new StringBuilder();
            reader.lines().forEach(builder::append);
            error.lines().forEach(errorBuilder::append);
            String outputString = builder.toString();
            String errorString = errorBuilder.toString();
        catch(IOException e) {
            // do something
        }
```

When I run this snippet from java, I get a python error from the `subprocess.check_output()` call.  The value of the `errorString` String is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_prog.py", line 9, in __main__
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My suspicion is that somewhere in the nested shells, the tempfile is not available, however, I can't understand why.

Any thoughts here?

edit:  The exact python subprocess call is like this:

```
def _exec_crf_test(input_text, model_path):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as input_file:
        input_file.write(utils.export_data(input_text))
        input_file.flush()
        return subprocess.check_output(
            ['crf_test', '--verbose=1', '--model', model_path, file.name]).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: I should add that the `crf_test` executable is on my PATH (ie, I can find it with `which crf_test`)

Comment: Check the full path or relative path. It can't find the file.

Comment: @Hayat Yes I understand the error message, but I don't know which file it can't find.  All of my file inputs are full paths from root.  The value of the `file.name` is also a full path from root.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the temp file. The error comes from `Popen`, so it's `crf_test` that it can't find. Try using the `shell=True` parameter to ensure that `PATH` is used.

Comment: @blhsing Ah yeah using `shell=True` at least indicates `/bin/sh: crf_test: command not found`

Comment: @blhsing Using full path of crf_test did the trick, thanks!